# 90s book about hieroglyphs on an alien planet?

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I'm looking for a book that I half-read when I was in high school in the early '90s. I believe it was published in 1990 or 1991.

It was about an alien female who was found on a newly discovered planet. Archaeologists found hieroglyphs on the planet. An expert in hieroglyphics was hired to communicate with the alien. If I remember correctly, the book cover shows the young alien fully clothed with long fingers.

I would really appreciate it if someone can name the book and author.

Comment: I have that one at home, but can't offhand remember the title or writer. I will look it up when I get home.

Comment: The girl has white hair, and the ruins she was found in were in Precolumbian style.

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure it's *A Whisper of Time* (1994) by Paula E. Downing.

From the description on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2545680.A_Whisper_of_Time):

> She was found alone lost in the stately ruins of an alien city. And when they hunted for the child's people, and found no clue that would lead them to the truth, they adopted her as humanity's first alien. Medoret grows up with the archaeologist who discovered her in her alien city, but dreams of her early years plague her, and as her curiosity grows, she begins to study the glyphs that were once carved into the stones of the alien ruins. Many mysteries of the alien land were waiting to be solved, and Medoret was determined to unravel every last one.

[image: A whisper of time cover]